# swift: How to set class to view controller without storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make slide out menu, for doing this i'm using SWRevealViewController. And I have to set class `"SWRevealViewController"` to my main view controller. I don't have `storyboard`. With storyboard its easy: Im going to view controller and in identity inspector change class name.

I know how to do this with storyboard but i don't know how to do this programmatically, without storyboard.

Thank you!)

Comment: Why don't you have any storyboard file ? Everything will be easier with a storyboard. Can you explain why can't / don't want to have a storyboard ?

Comment: Make auto layout with storyboard is hard for me. I'm using SnapKit.

Comment: Simply create empty views with their view controller in a storyboard file and add your subviews programmatically. Once you've added any view this way you can use SnapKit to setup the layout. IMO it's the easiest (the only?) way you can achieve this.

Comment: @Pyroh Do u know how I can set custom class's name without storyboard?

Comment: You don't have to set any name since you directly create these objects. Simply instantiate your view controller the way you'll instantiate any class: `let vc = SWRevealViewController(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I presume, you already have two view controllers:

1. Slide out menu (let's call it `SlideOutVC`)
2. Main view controller (`MainVC`).

Then all you have to do is create instances of those view controllers, create an `SWRevealViewController` instance programmatically, and pass instances of 1 and 2 to the `SWRevealViewController` as [the docs](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController#basic-api-description) say (check this link out).

It would look something along these lines (untested):

```
let slideOutVC = SlideOutVC(...)
let mainVC = MainVC(...)
//...
let revealVC = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController:slideOutVC, frontViewController:mainVC)
```

Then you just make `revealVC` the `rootViewController`.